# Wasync/Atmosphere Socket not opening in Android with an SSL URI

Tags: android, sockets, atmosphere

I have an android application that opens a socket connection to a server using wasync/atmosphere.  This works fine using http.  If I connect with SSL to an https address, the socket will not open.  I am able to communicate with a DefaultHttpClient to the https socket.  I am able to use the same code in a desktop application and have the socket connect with SSL.

When I attempt to open the socket, there is an exactly 60 second pause, and then the following exception:

java.net.ConnectException: wss://prod-responseware.dev.turningtechnologies.com/responseware/pollingParticipant/1437?X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-atmo-protocol=true&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0&X-Cache-Date=0
            at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:103)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:413)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:380)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelDisconnected(SslHandler.java:661)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelDisconnected(SslHandler.java:661)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Here is some of the socket code: 
http://pastebin.com/RxSdmirZ

I have tried updating my libraries and replacing netty with grizzly.

Any ideas of what I can try or further ways to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by replacing netty with grizzly.  I must have needed to update my other libraries to have it fully work.